# How can I concatenate one row to the previous row in a data frame, if a condition is met?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am an intermediate user of R and have a data set of ~850,000 rows that was edited through Stata, saved as a csv, but about .01% of the rows got split to the following row after column 11. I am trying to get the file back to its original form, with no split rows. I was using column 4 "type of" as the required condition, but someone below pointed out this won't work. I tested this and all object types in the data frame are indeed "integers". Maybe this would work if I changed the column "type of" for this problem, but here was what I tried:

```
wages <- for (i in wages) {
  if(typeof(wages[i,4]) == "integer") {
    cat(i-1, i)
  }
}
```

all I get is NAs.

When trying:

```
for (i in wages) {
  if(typeof(i[ ,4]) == "integer") {
    append(i-1, i, after = length(i-1))
  }
}
```

it says:
Error in `[.default`(i, , 4) : incorrect number of dimensions

I have spent hours searching for solutions and trying different methods with no success. Thanks in advance for any help.

Snippet of data:

```
WD County_Name State_Name   Cons_Code constructiondescription    wagegroup Rate_Effective_Date  hourly
113352                      CO20190006       Adams   Colorado     Highway                         SUCO2011-001           9/15/2011   22.67
113353                      CO20190004       Adams   Colorado Residential                         PLUM0058-011            7/1/2018   32.75
113354 (pipefitters exclude hvac pipe)   SOUTHWEST         CO        8001                   METRO         1352              100335 plumber
113355                      CO20190004       Adams   Colorado Residential                         PLUM0145-005            8/1/2016   24.58
       fringe Rate_Type                                                            Craft_Title    region st_abbr stcnty_fips    mr supergrp
113352   8.73      Open                       power equipment operator: broom/sweeper arapahoe SOUTHWEST      CO        8001 METRO     1352
113353  14.85       CBA                        plumber/pipefitter (plumbers include hvac pipe)                            NA             NA
113354      1                                                                                                             NA             NA
113355  10.47       CBA plumber (plumbers include hvac pipe) & pipefitters (exclude hvac pipe) SOUTHWEST      CO        8001 METRO     1352
        group key_craft key
113352 100335  operator   1
113353     NA            NA
113354     NA            NA
113355 100335   plumber   1
```

Reproducible data:

```
data <- data.frame(c("CO20190006","CO20190004","(pipefitters exclude hvac pipe)","CO20190004"), #1
                  c("Adams","Adams","SOUTHWEST","Adams"), #2
                  c("Colorado","Colorado","CO","Colorado"), #3
                  c("Highway","Residential","8001","Residential"), #4
                  c("","","METRO",""), #5
                  c("SUCO2011-001","PLUM0058-011","1352","PLUM0145-005"), #6
                  c("9/15/2011","7/1/2018","100335","8/1/2016"), #7
                  c("22.67","32.75","plumber","24.58"), #8
                  c("8.73","14.85","1","10.47"), #9
                  c("Open","CBA","","CBA"), #10
                  c("power equipment operator: broom/sweeper arapahoe","plumber/pipefitter (plumbers include hvac pipe)","",
                    "plumber (plumbers include hvac pipe) & pipefitters (exclude hvac pipe)"), #11
                  c("SOUTHWEST","","","SOUTHWEST"), #12
                  c("CO","","","CO"), #13
                  c("8001",NA,NA,"8001"), #14
                  c("METRO","","","METRO"), #15
                  c("1352",NA,NA,"1352"), #16
                  c("100335",NA,NA,"100335"), #17
                  c("operator","","","plumber"), #18
                  c("1",NA,NA,"1")) #19
colnames(data) <- c("WD","County_Name","State_Name","Cons_Code","constructiondescription","wagegroup","Rate_Effective_Date",
             "hourly","fringe","Rate_Type","Craft_Title","region","st_abbr","stcnty_fips","mr","supergrp","group",
             "key_craft","key")
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the data?

Comment: If one element of a vector is of class `"character"`, the entire vector is coerced to `"character"`. So if you're testing for integers you are (probably) doing it the wrong way. Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` where `df` is a data.frame showing the problem.

Comment: Example data would help, but for starters, in your second try when you say `for (i in wages)` that loops through each element in the data frame. You want to loop through rows, so would need to do something like `for (i in 1:length(wages$foo)) {if(typeof(wages[i,4] == "integer"))`.....

Comment: Thanks for all the edits - I have changed my answer to fit the updated reproducible data example.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should do the job:

```r
new_data <- NULL
i <- 1

while (i <= nrow(data)) {
  new_data <- rbind(new_data, data[i, ])
  if (all(is.na(data[i, c(14, 16, 17, 19)]))) {
    if (!paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1]) %in% levels(new_data[,11])) {
      levels(new_data[,11]) <- c(
        levels(new_data[,11]), paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1])
      )
    }
    new_data[nrow(new_data),11] <- paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1])
    new_data[nrow(new_data),] <- cbind(new_data[nrow(new_data),1:11], data[i+1,2:9])
    i <- i + 2
  } else {i <- i + 1}
}
```

Note that as it stands, your data frame (DF) stores *strings as factors* because when creating a DF using the [`data.frame()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/data.frame) function, one of the settings is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default. You can read more about [factors and their levels in data frames here](https://www.studytrails.com/r/core/datastructures_in_r_factors_data_frames/).

Therefore, in the code above, we first add a new row to the clean `new_data`:

```
new_data <- rbind(new_data, data[i, ])
```

Then we test whether that row is split by checking if there are `NA`s in columns 14, 16, 17, and 19:

```
if (all(is.na(data[i, c(14, 16, 17, 19)])))
```

If so, in order for us to be able to merge the cell in column 11 of the split row with the 1st cell of the following row, we first need to check whether that level already exists in that column and if not:

```
if (!paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1]) %in% levels(new_data[,11]))
```

it needs to be added to the list of levels before merging:

```
levels(new_data[,11]) <- c(levels(new_data[,11]), paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1]))
```

And then, finally, the merging (to complete the cell in column 11 of the split row) can be done:

```
new_data[nrow(new_data),11] <- paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1])
```

After that, the remaining missing columns are added to the split row in question:

```
new_data[nrow(new_data),] <- cbind(new_data[nrow(new_data),1:11], data[i+1,2:9])
```

#### Version LITE

Now, I am suspecting that all this checking for factors and adding new ones is taking some extra time, so I propose you may use a new version of this code, which **turns the implicated column 11 into just characters**, instead of factors. I think it makes sense in this particular data set, as specifically that column does not seem to be intended as factors anyway. That way, all the factor checking / adding can be skipped:

```
data[,11] <- as.character(data[,11])
new_data <- NULL
i <- 1

while (i <= nrow(data)) {
  new_data <- rbind(new_data, data[i, ])
  if (all(is.na(data[i, c(14, 16, 17, 19)]))) {
    new_data[nrow(new_data),11] <- paste(data[i,11], data[i+1,1])
    new_data[nrow(new_data),] <- cbind(new_data[nrow(new_data),1:11], data[i+1,2:9])
    i <- i + 2
  } else {i <- i + 1}
}
```

Let me know if this improved the speed!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The data is in data frame format. I switched the snippit for one with a better example & added reproducible code. I altered the question after taking into account Rui Barradas's comment. Though I believe this could work, if still using value "type of" to decipher the erroneous rows, since I am searching for the rows that contain the split half of the data.

Comment: Thank you much Brunox13. This does work, but it takes a long time to search through the data, then bind the columns. I have a pretty good/new PC and it has not finished after 30 minutes. Maybe if it searches for just two columns and then binds the whole row to the above row, that would be quicker? The code you listed is beyond my scope of knowledge so my attempts to alter it would likely be futile.

Comment: I altered the code a little so it should now run faster. I also added detailed explanations so that you understand what exactly is being done.